# Why do I get strings instead of integers when I scrape an HTML table in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table, rvest

I am having a difficult time scraping data tables from [iea.org][1]. I use the following code :

```
library("rvest")
url <- "http://www.iea.org/statistics/statisticssearch/report/?country=ZAMBIA&product=balances&year=2013"
energy <- url %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="stats-container"]/div[2]/table') %>%
  html_table()
head(energy)
```

Instead of having numbers in the cells of the table, the resulting table in R only contains letters. 
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: pictures are neither code nor data unless the question is about image processing.

Comment: The data is encoded. You are not allowed to scrape the statistics pages of the iea. Read the robots.txt file and the terms and conditions of the organisation.

Comment: The `robots.txt` is malformed if you believe it prohibits scraping, @phiver. `Disallow:` with a blank field does not mean you can't scrape (i.e. that would immediately cause a dismissal in court). I don't do global energy for a living, but I think the statistics data falls under PAMS. If so, that means: http://www.iea.org/t&c/termsandconditions-pams/ applies and it has (from 2 scanning reads) a pretty liberal "you can use this data if you give us credit and don't build a database from it". Where do you see scraping prohibited? I ask b/c I don't see what you're seeing.

Comment: To @phiver's point, the site owners used a pretty pathetic obfuscation technique that they provide decoding code for: http://www.iea.org/media/ieawebsite/styleassets/stats/stats.script.js. Said code took **eight** "programmers" to build and even had bugs along the way. All for simple base64 decoding. I won't post a solution if phiver can provide a solid link to "can't scrape" . If phiver cannot, I can post a pretty simple solution to this. Given that they went to the trouble of — albeit, pathetic — obfuscation _and_ **sell the data**, it is likely they really don't want you scraping this.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, `Disallow: /stats/ `. Though I agree that the terms are a bit liberal, but you are expected to pay for the use. But there is a guest account.

Comment: @phiver `/statistics/` is not `/stats/`. I'm not trying to be difficult. `robots.txt` exists for a reason and if they misconfigured and don't have Terms that prohibit scraping then I can't see an issue here (and I can pull the "I'm kind of an expert in this" card for web-scraping since I do it for a living).

Answer (score 1):

Until proven otherwise (or the site owners read up on how to use `robots.txt` and find a real lawyer to craft more explicit & restrictive T&Cs)…

I'll start with a non-"tidyverse" solution for this answer:

```
library(rvest)

x <- read_html("http://www.iea.org/statistics/statisticssearch/report/?country=ZAMBIA&product=balances&year=2013")

# find the table; note that a less "structural" selector will generally make  
# scraping code a bit less fragile.
xdf <- html_node(x, xpath=".//table[contains(., 'International marine')]")
xdf <- html_table(xdf)

# clean up column names
xdf <- janitor::clean_names(xdf)
```

Now, the columns are encoded as noted by the OP and in the question comment discussions:

```
xdf$oil_products
##  [1] "MA==" "Mzkx" "LTUw" "MA==" "LTUy" "MA==" "Mjkw" "MA==" "MQ==" "LTEw"
## [11] "MA==" "MA==" "MA==" "NjAx" "MA==" "MA==" "MA==" "LTE1" "MA==" "ODY2"
## [21] "MzQ2" "MzMy" "MTI0" "Nw==" "NDI=" "MjY=" "MA==" "NTA=" "NjM=" "MA=="
```

The `==` gives it away as base64 encoded (though the URL mentioned in the comments further confirms this). They encoded each character so we need to convert them from b64 first then convert to numeric:

```
# decode each column
lapply(xdf[2:12], function(.x) {
  as.numeric(
    sapply(.x, function(.y) {
      rawToChar(openssl::base64_decode(.y))
    }, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
  )
}) -> xdf[2:12]
```

A quick `str()` alternative view:

```
tibble::glimpse(xdf)
## Observations: 30
## Variables: 12
## $ x                    <chr> "Production", "Imports", "Exports", "International marine bunkers***", "International aviation bunkers***", "Stock c...
## $ coal                 <dbl> 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
## $ crude_oil            <dbl> 0, 618, 0, 0, 0, 21, 639, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -639, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
## $ oil_products         <dbl> 0, 391, -50, 0, -52, 0, 290, 0, 1, -10, 0, 0, 0, 601, 0, 0, 0, -15, 0, 866, 346, 332, 124, 7, 42, 26, 0, 50, 63, 0
## $ natural_gas          <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
## $ nuclear              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
## $ hydro                <dbl> 1142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1142, 0, 0, -1142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
## $ geothermal_solar_etc <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
## $ biofuels_and_waste   <dbl> 7579, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7579, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1661, 0, 0, 5918, 1479, 0, 4438, 4438, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
## $ electricity          <dbl> 0, 6, -93, 0, 0, 0, -87, 0, 0, 1144, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -26, -98, 933, 549, 2, 382, 289, 59, 23, 0, 10, 0, 0
## $ heat                 <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
## $ total                <dbl> 8809, 1016, -143, 0, -52, 21, 9651, 0, 1, -9, 0, 0, 0, -39, 0, 0, -1661, -41, -98, 7805, 2462, 335, 4945, 4734, 101,...
```

And an enhanced print:

```
tibble::as_tibble(xdf)
## # A tibble: 30 x 12
##                                    x  coal crude_oil oil_products natural_gas nuclear hydro geothermal_solar_etc biofuels_and_waste electricity  heat
##                                <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>                <dbl>              <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
##  1                        Production    88         0            0           0       0  1142                    0               7579           0     0
##  2                           Imports     0       618          391           0       0     0                    0                  0           6     0
##  3                           Exports     0         0          -50           0       0     0                    0                  0         -93     0
##  4   International marine bunkers***     0         0            0           0       0     0                    0                  0           0     0
##  5 International aviation bunkers***     0         0          -52           0       0     0                    0                  0           0     0
##  6                     Stock changes     0        21            0           0       0     0                    0                  0           0     0
##  7                              TPES    88       639          290           0       0  1142                    0               7579         -87     0
##  8                         Transfers     0         0            0           0       0     0                    0                  0           0     0
##  9           Statistical differences     0         0            1           0       0     0                    0                  0           0     0
## 10                Electricity plants     0         0          -10           0       0 -1142                    0                  0        1144     0
## # ... with 20 more rows, and 1 more variables: total <dbl>
```

The tidyverse is a bit cleaner:

```
decode_cols <- function(.x) {
  map_dbl(.x, ~{
    openssl::base64_decode(.x) %>% 
      rawToChar() %>% 
      as.numeric()
  })
}

html_node(x, xpath=".//table[contains(., 'International marine')]") %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-x), decode_cols)
```